# LyX: Two exercises one after the other with nothing in between with the Theorems module?

Tags: lyx, theorems

I'm writing lecture notes in LyX, and I want to add automatically numbered exercises to each section, using the module "Theorems (Numbered by Section)".

I want to have several different exercises at the end of each section, for the students to solve as homework assignments, so I will not provide solutions within the lecture notes.

However, the problem is that when I define an Exercise environment in LyX, all of the lines within that environment correspond to the **same** exercise number. If I then change to a another environment, write something, and then create another Exercise environment, that starts a new exercise with a new number. But I could not find a way to just write two exercises one after the other without anything in between. How might that be done?

To summarize, what I want is simply something like this:

Exercise 1.1: Blah blah blah

Exercise 1.2: Blah blah blah

Seems like this should be easy to do, but I could not find how to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Insert > Separated Exercise Below, or use the shortcut that is shown next to the menu entry (for me on Linux the default is Alt + p Return which means you first do the combination Alt + p, then release, then press return). Here is a screenshot of the menu entry:

[image]

And here is the end result:

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!